# Is this the correct way to parse JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

I am a newbie to the world of JSON, jQuery, etc but when I saw a tutorial on how to feed Wordpress content through JSON using jQuery I was excited. Until I ran the code on my local machine. Its supposed to read a Wordpress post that is already JSON plugin-ed, but when I view it from my browser it shows nothing.

The question is this: Is the tutorial still valid or has the jQuery protocol changed since the tutorial was published? The problem is, this is supposed to be the easiest part of my journey. If I can't get it right, the rest of the tutorial looses integrity and boy do I want to get it right!

Here is the code: Thanks all!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <header>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function readSinglePost (url, target_div) {
                var URL = url
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        jQuery(target_div).html(data.post.content);
                    }
                });
            }

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#title").html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
                // you might have to change this url
                varurl = "http://localhost/public_html/?json=get_post&dev=1&p=1";
                vartarget_div = "#contents";
                readSinglePost(url, target_div);
            });
        </script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="title"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI your `header` element should be `head`.

Comment: See this link for more http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/getjson/

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out now! Although I have changed the <header> to <head> still not working...though someone suggests that it might not work on local file...but I am using localserver on WAMP...could this be  the problem?

Answer (score 0):

<s>It sounds like you're running this page from a local `file://` URL. If you are, AJAX requests won't work. You need to run it from a server.</s>

EDIT: Oh, now i see the issue. You don't have a space between the `var` keyword and the variable name.

You could also simplify the `readSinglePost` function like this:

```
       function readSinglePost (url, target_div) {
            jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
// use the simple getJSON shortcut, and don't bother redefining the variable
                jQuery(target_div).html(data.post.content);
            });
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#title").html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
            // you might have to change this url
            var url = "localhost/Samples/sample1/?p=13115&json=1"; // public_html?
            var target_div = "#contents";
// you could even get rid of this and just pass the value directly on the next line:
// readSinglePost(url, "#contents");
// same thing with the url variable.
            readSinglePost(url, target_div);
        });
```

Comment: No boss..from a local server (localhost with WAMPSERVER already running)

Comment: @user3610307 Edited. I think i solved it this time. :)

Comment: Thanks for that insight! But yet, I have put spaces on both var url and var target_div, then on one of them at a time..yet, there is still no result...sorry for being a pain...and thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @user3610307 Have you checked that the URL you're requesting is accurate? That `public_html` part looks suspicious.

Comment: I realised the mistake after I posted the code..the correct link is http://localhost/Samples/sample1/?p=13115&json=1" and yes, when I access the link it displays the post in a json format

Comment: I updated the post with some simplified code. Maybe one of the changes will fix it for you?

Comment: Thanks again! Maybe its my machine. But the code is not working!

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's dev console?

Comment: This is the error:Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined newapp.html:22
(anonymous function) newapp.html:22
o jquery.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B

Comment: I have also uploaded the file online at http://wtoalabi.ipage.com/android/newapp.html and the JSON page I am trying to read is at http://wtoalabi.ipage.com/android/api/?json=get_post&dev=1&id=1

Comment: Pick a case. You define your variable as `URL` and use it as `url`. I recommend lowercase as `URL` is a native function. Also, you should replace those `<header>` tags with `<head>`.